# JSONArray not able to parse

Tags: android

Sorry for this simple question, I am confused because I am not able to get the data from the `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`. Exception is generated at this line:

```
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(jsonStr);
```

[image]

Exception error

```
 Json parsing error: No value for {"image":"John","description":30,"city":"New York"}
```

Comment: First of all, it's not an Array, it's just a Json Object.. Second, You are getting 3 elements but, you are requesting for 5 in your for.loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an array in object...!

Remove for circle and parse object like this:

```
String id= jsonObj.getString("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

Json arrays start with `[` and end with `]`.

In your response, you don't have these signs so you don't have a Json array.

To solve this problem, just use a Json object as Farshad said:

```
String id = jsonObj.getString("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Firstly, Remove the line JsonArray, because your Json is not an Array, remove the for loop too.. since it's not an Array, you don't need for loop

Secondly, make these changes in your code:

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);

String image = jsonObj.getString("image");
int desc = jsonObj.getInt("description")
String city = jsonObj.getString("city");
```

Now, you can use the string anywhere you want. Remove everything else, because you are not getting all those as a response.

Hope it helps.